# What are the default settings for "Remote Management" under Sharing System Preference pane in macOS?

Tags: macos, catalina, screen-sharing

I accidentally toggled the System Preferences → Sharing → Remote Management setting to **Only these users:**, and, now when I try to toggle it back to **All users:**, it asks what privileges to enable. But I don't know what the default privileges were and I don't want to open my computer up to any potential security issues.

Could someone take a screenshot of the default settings and post that up so that I can reset them to the OS defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never enabled Remote Management on my Mac and these are the options corresponding to the default selection **All users**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and sharing a screenshot of the default settings.

Answer (score 2):

The default state is off, turn off both screen sharing and remote management main toggles.

All the sub portions don’t matter when you have the main items off for screen sharing and for remote management. Turn on only the sub options you want when you enable it now that you know they exist to be selected. If you’re really worried, deselect all sub items before you disable the overall item.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  The feature is disabled. I also wanted to ensure that the underlying settings for the feature were still in their default state.  I should have been more clear on the settings state, my apologies.

Comment: No - thank you for asking and more importantly selecting an answer.  Very  good post, would answer again :) cheers @AnilNatha